# Rebind Win+F hotkey in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys, key-binding

I want to remove the standard "Find" from <kbd>[image: wind]</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and bind the key combination to my own program.

Is there a way to perform this task without any hook applications, for example, changes made through registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention "hook applications", guess you know about [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm) and the like. You can disable all built-in Windows hotkeys except <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> by making the following change to the registry (should work in XP+):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
NoWinKeys REG_DWORD 0x00000001 (1)
```

To make <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> launch a custom app would indeed require a keyboard hook; I don't believe you can do without one. The **Scancode Map** REG_BINARY value under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout` (which you can edit easily using programs such as [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/)) only lets you remap single keys.