# How do I disable Windows-F

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

How do I reclaim <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> hotkey and use it for my own purposes (Everything search hotkey?) in Windows 10

Comment: Because the oppressive comment and edit culture of SO discourages answers and encourages the inconsequential, fruitless, and the unnecessary? Because the time-based format means that 90% of questions that don't get an answer within one day never get an answer at all? (Yes, stats may have changed a bit since the numbers were scraped in 2016) Are you being serious? You guys consistently disincentivize the exact kind of questions and answers you ostensibly want. This is an incongruity commonly discussed in Meta. Don't blame me for acting in self-interest after you stopped replying. I don't care.

Comment: Open the Settings app you can see all ways to open settings app in Windows 10.
Click the Privacy app and sorrel down to Feedback & Diagnostics.
Under Set the option called "Windows should ask for my feedback" to "Never"

Comment: Thanks vembutech, I have already done this. I am trying to disable the Win + F hotkey specifically, so I can use it for different purposes.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't use 'Feedback Hub' on Windows 10, you can remove it. Then 'Win + F' shortcut will be also removed.

To remove 'Feedback Hub', open start menu, scroll down to find 'Feedback Hub' icon, click mouse right button on the mouse, and click 'Remove' on the popup.

Comment: Nice! I'm using the windows key as the host key in the virtual box. Who needs the feedback hub after all? :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to try [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)?

From its Wikipedia page: AutoHotkey is a free, open-source custom scripting language for Microsoft Windows, initially aimed at providing easy keyboard shortcuts or hotkeys, fast macro-creation and software automation that allows users of most levels of computer skill to automate repetitive tasks in any Windows application. User interfaces can easily be extended or modified by AutoHotkey (for example, overriding the default Windows control key commands with their Emacs equivalents).

You should check out this SuperUser question as well: [Rebind Win+F hotkey in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/537401/rebind-winf-hotkey-in-windows-7)

Disclaimer: I haven't ever used AutoHotkey so I have no idea if it has what you want.

Comment: I'll try AHK next, but the key difference is that nothing is bound to Win + F in Windows 10, or at least it is possible to use it for other purposes. Yet in the latest (millennium?) update they bound it the Feedback, and it doesn't obey the rules of other WIn key hotkeys.

Comment: AHK can definitely disable the Win+F combination or make it do something else if you want. I know this because I'm running a script that does that right now. Here's how you disable it: `#f::return`. If you want it to do something else, add some line breaks between `#f::` and `return` then put code in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, it seems that using `gpedit` or `regedit` might do the trick (after some workthrough, of course). I'm not sure what you're trying to remap the command to, but [**this link**](http://www.isumsoft.com/it/disable-win-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-10/) might help.

Comment: Using "NoWinKeys 1" disables everything EXCEPT Win + F, I am not sure whether the gpedit change works on Win+F, but either way I do not wish to disable ALL Win keys.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, Just uninstall the Feedback Program. Search for it on start menu and hit uninstall

[Showing menu with the uninstall button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g2Pt.png)